# How can I force a property value on a derived object?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, windows-forms-designer

I want to create a class that derives from a ListView object.

```
class MyListView : ListView
{
}
```

I have tried a few things to force the default `View` property but nothing I seem to do has any effect in the properties of the object during design time.

Some of the things I have tried are...

```
public MyListView():base()
{
    base.View = View.Tile;
}

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[DefaultValue(View.Tile)]
new public View View
{
    get {
        return base.View;
    }
    set {
        base.View = value;
    }
}

protected override void InitLayout()
{
    base.InitLayout();
    base.View = View.Tile;
}
```

So my question is how can I either force a value to always be persistent on the `View` property or how can I set a default value for it and hide the property in my new class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal cases it's enough to override the property and put your desired value in both getter and setter. But `View` property of the `ListView` is a special case. the `ListViewDesigner` adds a shadowed `View` property to the designer.

If you take a look at `ListViewDesigner` class, you will see regardless of your `new` View property, the designer uses `View` property of the base class: `((ListView) base.Component).View = value;`.

**What can we do to force the `ListView` to use a specific View in design-time?**

You can decorate your new `View` property with `Browsable(false)`. This way it doesn't show the `View` property in property grid, but it shows the property in the control action list.

To remove that action list, you can register a different `Designer` for your control, for example `ControlDesigner`:

```
[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        this.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Tile;
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    new public View View
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Windows.Forms.View.Tile;
        }
        set
        {
            base.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Tile;
        }
    }
}
```

Also as another option instead of registering new designer for control, you can get the designer instance for the control and clear its action lists.

Don't forget to add reference to `System.Design.dll` and add `using System.Windows.Forms.Design;`

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for the example.

Comment: OK so where does `ControlDesigner` come from?

Comment: Add reference to `System.Design.dll` than add  `using System.Windows.Forms.Design;`